# OpenSSH on windows server can't connect with windows permissions

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, openssh

I followed these instructions to a T:

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

For some reason, I can't login to my server. Says it's connecting and then I get this error:

```
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "damien".

Authentication failed.
```

I know that I'm using the proper permissions so what gives? The SSH server is definitely running. This is on a Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: there is a reference to the session log for more detail.. what does the session log say?

Comment: 12612 16:45:59 998 Accepted password for damien from 216.***.***.*** port 2276 ssh2

Comment: How are you connecting? What does the client log say? What does the server log say? Show more context.

Comment: I'm connecting using WinSCP